# How to write a sparse matrix in a text file in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix as A_n. type of A_n is "scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix".

for example, A_n is:

```
(16, 0) 1.0
(71, 1) 1.0
(74, 3) 1.0
(72, 12)    1.0
  .          .
  .          .
(32, 17)    1.0
(64, 17)    1.0
(53, 19)    1.0
(73, 20)    1.0
(52, 21)    1.0
(52, 22)    1.0
(44, 26)    1.0
(53, 26)    1.0
(87, 26)    1.0
```

I want to write all of A_n in a text file in python as follows:

```
16 0 1.0
71 1 1.0
74 3 1.0
.
.
```

or

```
(16, 0) 1.0
(71, 1) 1.0
(74, 3) 1.0
.
.
```

I would be very grateful if you guide me

Comment: Do you need to access it afterwards, or do you only need to write it to a file? Why are you saving it to a file?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with a double for-loop, and then printing a line to stdout if the specific `i,j` element is set?

Comment: I just want to write it in a text file as same above form. then I want to open this file in excel.

Comment: No, there is not. What is its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply convert the spare matrix object to a string using `str(sparse_matrix)` and then write it to a file after changing the maxprint attribute to spare_matrix.shape[0].

```
sparse_matrix.maxprint = sparse_matrix.shape[0]
with open("spare_matrix.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(str(sparse_matrix)) 
    file.close()
```

Comment: This code is correct but does not write all matrix elements in the file.
this code Ignores some rows and replaces it with ": :".For example, between the two lines (72, 12) and (32, 17) in A_n The sign ": :" was written.

Comment: I have updated the code above and changed the maxprint attribute before converting to a string, this should solve it. I had to go read the scipy source code for this xD. 

Hopefully this does it for you

Comment: This is still incomplete. It only prints entries up to the number of rows. It should be `sparse_matrix.maxprint = sparse_matrix.count_nonzero()` to include all non-zero data.

Answer (score 1):

Here **'i'** will go over rows of your matrix A_n and **'j'** will go only over the non-zero columns for **i-th** row of A_n.

```
file = open('sparse_matrix.txt','w')

for i in range(A_n.shape[0]):
    for j in A_n[i].nonzero()[1]:
        file.write(str(i)+' ' +str(j)+' '+str(A_n[i,j])+'\n')
file.close()
```